# Floating Window overlays on facebook share dialog

Tags: android, facebook

I've implemented a floating window and insert it by WindowManager with the following parameters:

```
mParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
mParams.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
mParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH;
mFloatingManager.updateView(mView, mParams);
```

In this view there's also a facebook share button. I open facebook share dialog with the following code:

```
for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList)
{
    if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook.composer.shareintent"))
    {
        final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
        final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
        shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shareIntent.setComponent(name);
        context.startActivity(shareIntent);
        break;
    }
}
```

However, my floating view overlays on facebook share dialog and that's not my intention; Facebook share dialog should overlay on my floating view. Any way to resolve it?

Comment: You won't be able to do this. TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT is used for top-level windows, meaning above regular app windows.

Comment: @SimonMarquis so what level should it be?

Comment: You won't be able to achieve this as an Android app.